# Коллекция на C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Доброго времени суток. Начинаю изучать Unity и, как следствие, работаю с C#. Подскажите пожалуйста аналог ArrayList<> на Java в C#. Требуется хранить массив кнопок Button. Пробовал использовать `List<Button>` из `System.Collections.Generic;`, вроде бы все нормально, но не знаю как получить элемент по индексу. В Java я бы использовал `.get()`, а как тут непонятно. Доки читал, аналога `.get()` не нашел.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для обращения к элементу коллекции используйте [индексное](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/0ebtbkkc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) `[i]` свойство:

```
List<Button> buttons = ...;
Button firstButton = buttons[0];
```

Comment: Спасибо! А не подскажете аналог `.SetActive()` в `UI Button` для `UI Image`? Картинку требуется делать видимой/невидимой.

Comment: @Igor, нет такой функции для UI Image.

Comment: В принципе подходит использовать `.CrossFadeAlpha(0, 0, false);`